# Safari bug using CSS transition-delay and CSS filters

Tags: css, safari

I'm having an issue with CSS transition-delay not working correctly in Safari when used to transition CSS filters. It works fine in Chrome but in Safari the animation happens then happens again after the delay time has elapsed.

Anyone else seen this before or found a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

https://codepen.io/selfctrl/pen/GRRZeWe

```
.gray-dog {
    filter: grayscale(0);
    transition: filter 0.5s ease-in-out;
     transition-delay: 1s;
}

.gray-dog:hover {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at these examples https://codepen.io/r2k/pen/QdwXzY . Btw I have experimented the same issue with your code..

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Safari still has this bug. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution for this.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383142/why-is-my-css-filter-transition-applying-early-in-safari